# allow_url_fopen is on but phpinfo says off

Tags: php

Since either when I updated the server to PHP7 or when I enabled AutoSSL for my server I has not been able upload files. My error is as follows

```
fopen(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```

I have no idea where allow_url_fopen=0 is coming from because in both the global php.ini and the php.ini inside of the sub domain are using stating

```
allow_url_fopen=On
allow_url_include = On
```

In phpinfo() I see where my php.ini file is...

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File   /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.ini
```

When I open this php.ini file I see that allow_file_fopen is "On"

```
; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as fil$
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On
```

But in the same phpinfo() file I see allow_file_fopen is off

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen Off Off
allow_url_include   Off Off
```

From another stack exchange thread I was told to try the following code which turns out it is OFF

```
if (ini_get("allow_url_fopen") == 'On') {
echo "allow_url_fopen is ON";
} else {
echo "allow_url_fopen is OFF";
}
```

Previously I did get this working by using the following code in my controller, but this no longer works for a reason I do not know

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);
```

I am using Laravel 5.2 and Image intervention package to deal with the images that get uploaded. As i said this was all working before PHP7 and AutoSSL

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart your webserver (Apache?) after modifying php.ini?

Comment: Yes I did. But still nothing has changed

Comment: Please type `php --ini` and see, if your installation is loading other ini-files as well. If so (especially with cpanel) there might be a chance, that the setting is disabled in an additional ini-file and therefore overrides your (manual) setting.

Comment: use "echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion(); "to check php version. If it is not php7 then edit the appropriate ini file

Comment: @Confused - `Current PHP version: 7.0.18`

Comment: @dognose Upon typing `php --ini` with both root and the offending account, it says I am using `/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini` But still when I edit this file it says `allow_url_fopen = On` something is skew whiff!

Comment: Have you tried changing a different setting in your php.ini file? If you change a different setting does it apply?

Comment: I just changed `short_open_tag` then restarted Apache but it didnt change a thing. Should I try disabling PHP55 and PHP56?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find where `allow_url_fopen` was switched off inside of WHM by editing the "MultiPHP INI Editor" section. From there I selected PHP7. The first option it gave me to to enable `allow_url_fopen`. This fixed my error.

I couldn't find where `allow_url_fopen` was disabled at all through SSH. I guess it is because I didn't understand the upgrade procedure from PHP5 to PHP7 and that I had PHP7 enabled only per account through cPanel though Root apeared to be still using PHP5 for php.ini.

Comment: I've used screenshots [from this page](https://www.hostinet.com/formacion/panel-alojamiento/activar-desactivar-allow-url-fopen-selector-php-cpanel/) as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The configuration of pool was disabled the option:

**A) First I tried to found which file is modifying the setting:**

```
    # cd /etc/php
    # grep -r allow_url_fopen

7.3/fpm/pool.d/worpresspool1.conf:php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
7.3/fpm/php.ini:allow_url_fopen = On
7.3/cli/php.ini:allow_url_fopen = On
```

**B) Then I edited the file**

```
    # vi /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/worpresspool1.conf
```

and commenting the above line with `;`:

```
    ;php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
```

**C) In my case I've restarted php-fpm service because I'm using Fast-cgi**

```
    # systemctl restart php7.3-fpm
```

Comment: Good answer, but you may want to improve your formatting by using code tags, and bold for your A, B, and C headers.

Comment: Thanks nettie, I've to learn. Excuse me also for my bad english. I tryied to follow your suggestion to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In WHM's MultiPHPManager, Under  PHP-FPM INI Settings,
Treat URLs as files (allow_url_fopen) - CHECK THIS ON
Block domain from changing the setting - UNCHECK THIS (Important)
Then Restart PHP-FPM Service, It works. Meanwhile, make sure it is Enabled at Domain level.