# production.ERROR: get_headers(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, server, configuration, cpanel

for above error I enabled `allow_url_fopen` in CPanel, even though I am still getting error.

How to fix it?

[image: You can see in screenshot Configure PHP INI basic settings]

Comment: check your phpinfo(); (or you can use php-cli as well) is it showing on or off

Comment: you can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543297/allow-url-fopen-is-on-but-phpinfo-says-off)

Comment: @bhucho where to check it

Comment: create a new php file in public folder, phpinfo.php and add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`  to it, also don't forget to remove it after use